# Current date displayed in US rather than expected format as it was previously

Tags: excel, vba, date-formatting

This Excel VBA code does not work anymore.

```vb
Private Sub cmdAjouter_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Achats"

lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("M" & lr).Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")

'[...]

End Sub
```

Today we are the 11th February 2020 , it should return the date as "11/02/2020" (French format) but it returns "02/11/2020" (US format).

Comment: the date format will follow whatever the regional settings of windows is. Perhaps your machines region was altered?

Comment: The cell itself is  set as Date format (Short Date) with formatting dd/mm/yyyy,

Comment: that may be so, but the `Format` function will set the cell value with a string that the cell will then try to convert to a date. Try this to prove my point, simply change you date format to the opposite of what you want, and you will get want you wanted. `ws.Range("M" & lr).Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: @ArcherBird : My regional settings in Windows are set to French BUT my Excel is in English (for some questions of compatibility with other programs I use). Date formats are set the same way (dd/mm/aaaa) in both windows and Excel ! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to store it as the actual `Date` instead of a `String` and just use the `.NumberFormat` property instead to format it, that way is doesn't try to convert it again based on your regional settings.

```
ws.Range("M" & lr).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
ws.Range("M" & lr).Value = Date
```

<sub>Your way would probably work fine if the date was something like February 13, since then there is no way it would get confused about 13 being a month.</sub>